# SPSS File Subsetting using R

Tags: r, spss

Very basic question from my side. I need to subset my SPSS file into multiple pieces. It is the month column highlighted with the red block in the snippet. It has 3 values 48,49 and 50 in one single column.

How can i subset the SPSS file like we do in data frames using the command. dt[dt$month == 48,].

Would appreciate your inputs to it.

[image: Sample SPSS File]

Comment: So you want to subset using SPSS, not R?

Comment: I want to subset using R only.